# Add events to smarty streets control

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, smartystreets

I'm using smarty street auto-complete control. I am trying to a attach a keydown event to facilitate selection by using the "ENTER".

```
$('body').on('keydown', '.smarty-active-suggestion', function(event) {

  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Not sure why this is not working. The code is @ http://plnkr.co/edit/1OdVQ81s4BbE9RO2Usv4?p=preview

Any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did either answers solve your problem? Would you mind accepting one

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that I had to change to get this to work was to put the code inside of this `$(document).ready(function() {` I think this will make sure that the body is loaded before you attach the listener to it.

Also, I was able to get it to react only when the enter button was pressed and to alert the selected address with this code

```
$('body').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      alert($(".smarty-active-suggestion").text());
    }
  });
```

This will check that the key pressed was ENTER by checking it's keyCode.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery selector you are using body as class.

```
$('.body').on
```

Comment: That was a typo to create  the plunkr . If I use $('body').on it does not work